# how to add numbers separated by comma in a string

Tags: php, numbers

I have a string 25,34,45,46 I need to add these values.

Means Result should be 25+34+45+46 = 150. How to do this using php

Comment: This is so simple by using explode

Comment: Please add the code, what you have tried till  now :)

Comment: Have you done any minimal research into how to do this?

Comment: Is it a quiz for us? You should have tried something before you ask here

Comment: @umair, @i alarmed alien.  Sorry to bother you guys. I am not a developer. I tried google but I failed. thats why I asked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use `explode()` will return an array and after use `array_sum()` to get sum of array values

```
$str='25,34,45,46';
$arr = explode(',', $str);
echo array_sum($arr); // 150
```

or

```
 echo array_sum(explode(',', $str));
```

Comment: Why are you answering simple questions without? User has made no efforts

Comment: @Umair because it's still a question

Comment: @Umair what you waiting for? i understand the question and giving an answer

Comment: This doesn't deserve a downvote. It's not up to you whether to decide what question he wants to answer. @Umair

Comment: Questions without effort should be downvoted @Umair, but not necessarily the answers. Both of the answers are correct and will work.

Answer (score 0):

This works as you're exploding the string by a deliemeter which means splitting the string into an array, next array_sum calculates the sum of the numerical values of the elements and returns the sum. It will also ignore all non-numerical values.

```
$string = '25,34,45,46';
$array = explode(",", $string);
echo array_sum($array);
```

[**Working Demo**](http://3v4l.org/pMFn9)

Answer (score 0):

Method with `array_sum()` was already answered twice, so here is some other "evil" example:

```
$string = '25,34,45,46';
$string = str_replace(',', '+', $string);
$sum = eval('return ' . $string . ';');
```

<kbd>[**demo**](https://eval.in/211842)</kbd>